# Replacing empty <p></p> with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get rid of empty paragraphs using `replace` with a regex, but not having luck.

```
return text.replace('/(<p><\/p>)+/g', '');
```

[I've tested the regex `/(<p><\/p>)+/g` in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iV1oF5/1) and it seems to be ok. What am I doing wrong?

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/r6ox38ad/1/)

Comment: You'd be better off finding `p` elements with empty `textContent` and removing them.

Comment: you don't need quotes `'`, or the `+`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 7):

You should remove the quotes:

```
return text.replace(/(<p><\/p>)+/g, '');
```

Comment: Right :) I knew it was something stupid! I'll accept the answer whenever I can!

Answer (score 5):

Almost there ... but a regex in JS isn't a string

Your's

```
return text.replace('/(<p><\/p>)+/g', '');
```

Try this

```
return text.replace(/(<p><\/p>)+/g, '');
```